# Why am I getting undefined while the variables contain the required data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing a project in which I want to implement the ability to authenticate by email and password using firebase, but as soon as the user enters his email and password into the form and clicks on the button, I get the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:136:55)
    at _fail (assert.ts:65:9)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:177:9)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:195:27)
    at async createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email_and_password.ts:230:20)
    at async handleSubmit (Signup.tsx:13:7)
```

Also I get this response from the server:

```
error
: 
{code: 400, message: "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",…}
code
: 
400
errors
: 
[{message: "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION", domain: "global", reason: "invalid"}]
message
: 
"ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION"
```

Earlier, I was told that the reason for this error is that I am sending incorrect data, and when I decided to check what is being sent to the server in signUp function

```
console.log("email: " + email + ", password: " + password);
```

To my surprise I recieved: email: undefined, password: undefined.

And I really do not understand why it turns out that when I check the contents of the email and password variables - I get what the user entered into the form while the signup function sends undefined...

My firebase.ts file:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

interface FirebaseOptions {
  apiKey: string;
  authDomain: string;
  projectId: string;
  storageBucket: string;
  messagingSenderId: string;
  appId: string;
}
const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

My AuthContext.tsx file where the authentication functions are stored:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

interface IUserData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface IContext {
  signUp: any;
  logIn: any;
  logOut: any;
  user: any;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<IContext | null>(null);

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [user, setUser]: any = useState({});

  function signUp({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    console.log("email: " + email + ", password: " + password);//I'm getting undefined here
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logIn({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut({}) {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signUp, logIn, logOut, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function UserAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Sign Up file in which the form is located that the user submits and the handleSubmit is called:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function Signup() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const { user, signUp }: any = UserAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(email); //Correct value from the form
      console.log(password); //Correct value from the form
      await signUp(email, password); //SignUp function is called from UserAuth which sends undefined
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type={"email"}
                placeholder={"Email or phone number"}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type={"password"}
                placeholder={"Password"}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button>
                Sign Up
              </button>
              <p>
                <span>
                  Already subscribed to our service?
                </span>
                <Link to={"/login"}>
                  Sign In
                </Link>
              </p>
            </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I spent many hours trying to solve this problem but unfortunately it didn't work. Anonymous authentication does not interest me, I need the email and password to be sent to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two arguments to signUp function (two strings):

```
await signUp(email, password)
```

and in the `signUp` function you have an object:

```
function signUp({ email, password }: IUserData) {
```

so you need to change this function call in `handleError` method to:

```
await signUp({email: email, password: password})
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to put any instead IUserData: `function signUp({ email, password }: any) {
    console.log("email: " + email + ", password: " + password);
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }` I'm getting the same result - undefined and subsequent errors from firebase

Comment: I updated my answer with the code you should use when you calling the function in `handleError` method

Comment: Oh my god, you are my savior!) Really works, thank you very much!